# How do I determine the SP and Rollup version of an Exchange installation?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2007, patch-management

How do I determine the SP version number and Rollup version of an Exchange installation?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh135098%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx

Answer (score 6):

**Slow method**

Open "Programs and Features", select view updates, and search for the relevant Exchange 2010 patch.

**Fast method**

Run this command in Powershell

```
 gcm exsetup | %{$_.fileversioninfo}
```

Then use this URL to decipher the version number: 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/240.exchange-server-and-update-rollups-build-numbers-en-us.aspx
This site seems to have more versions than the former - my Exchange version, 14.03.0123.004, wasn't listed on the former, but I found it here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh135098.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 5):

I created a PowerShell function to retrieve the proper version information for Exchange 2007, 2010 and 2013. My blog [post](http://binarynature.blogspot.com/2013/04/get-exchange-server-version-and-update-info-with-powershell.html) includes the code and some usage examples. Since the function is over 200 lines, I will not include it here. The following is some sample usage and output of the function:

#### Get Installed Updates (Cumulative and Update Rollups) for a Single Server

```
[PS] Get-ExchangeServerPlus -cn exch01 | select -ExpandProperty update | ft inst*,upd*,desc* -AutoSize

InstallDate UpdateBuild Description
----------- ----------- -----------
11/11/2012  8.3.279.5   Update Rollup 8-v2 for Exchange Server 2007 Service Pack 3 (KB2756497)
02/18/2013  8.3.298.3   Update Rollup 10 for Exchange Server 2007 Service Pack 3 (KB2788321)
```

#### Output All Exchange Server Object Properties with Installed Updates

```
Get-ExchangeServerPlus | % {"Name`t: $($_.Name)"; "Version`t: $($_.Version)"; "Edition`t: $($_.Edition)"; "Build`t: $($_.Build)"; "Role`t: $($_.Role)"; "OSVer`t: $($_.OSVer)"; "OSSP`t: $($_.OSSP)"; "OSArch`t: $($_.OSArch)"; if ($_.Update) { $_ | select -ExpandProperty update | ft inst*,upd*,desc* -auto } else { [Environment]::NewLine }}

...
Name    : EXCH160-02
Version : 2013
Edition : Enterprise
Build   : 15.0.620.29
Role    : MB,CAS
OSVer   : Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Datacenter
OSSP    : 0
OSArch  : 64-bit

InstallDate UpdateBuild Description
----------- ----------- -----------
04/21/2013  15.0.620.29 Microsoft Exchange Server 2013 Cumulative Update 1
...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Get-ExchangeServer | ft AdminDisplayVersion
```

Comment: How does this add to the other answers?  More detail would improve this answer

Comment: This (AdminDisplayVersion) does not reveal what RU has been installed, as explained in http://blogs.technet.com/b/rmilne/archive/2013/10/29/how-to-check-exchange-2010-ru-version.aspx